# Python windows popup table text grab

Tags: python

By using python to how grab all the text and table data from some windows based popup titled as search

Pywinnauto win32api  library I have tried but unable to do.. please help .. I am a beginner in python  unable to grab text from a table .. thank you

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the window you're trying to pull the data from along with a sample data? That would give more context.